# Select sibling of a shape in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a markup that looks like this which is created using d3.

```
<g transform="translate(441,114)">
    <rect x="50" y="-30" width="50" height="60" id="yesDecision" class="hoverNodeundefined" style="fill: rgb(51, 110, 123);"></rect>
    <text x="80" y="0" class="id ">Yes</text>
    <circle class="node fixed" r="58" style="fill: rgb(30, 139, 195); stroke: rgb(21, 97, 136);" transform="scale(1.0)"></circle>
    <text x="0" y="20" class="id">Segment</text>
    <rect class="edit-event node-hover-button" x="-20" y="-70" height="29" width="29" rx="15" ry="15"></rect>
    <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="icon-segment.svg" width="30" height="30" x="-15" y="-30" class="id"></image>
    <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="edit-automation.svg" width="16" height="16" x="-14" y="-65" class="edit-event-image node-hover-button"></image>
    <rect class="delete-event node-hover-button" x="-54" y="-54" height="29" width="29" rx="15" ry="15"></rect>
    <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="trash-automation.svg" width="20" height="20" x="-50" y="-50" class="delete-event-image node-hover-button"></image>
</g>
```

I have a mouseover event on the circle element with class `node`. I'm trying to hide and show the sibling elements of the circle with class `node-hover-elements` on hover of the circle. Is there a function in d3 similar to that of `siblings()` in jquery?

Also there will be multiple such `g` elements. I only want siblings of this element to be shown on hover.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a D3 answer: you can select the parent node...

```
d3.select(this.parentNode)
```

... and then selecting everything inside it with that given class:

```
d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll(".node-hover-button")
```

After that, you can do whatever you want with that selection.  For instance, changing the opacity of the siblings:

```js
d3.selectAll(".node-hover-button").attr("opacity", 0).attr("pointer-events", "none");
d3.select("circle").on("mouseover", function() {
    d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll(".node-hover-button").attr("opacity", 1);
}).on("mouseout", function() {
    d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll(".node-hover-button").attr("opacity", 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <g transform="translate(100,50)">
    <rect x="50" y="-30" width="50" height="60" id="yesDecision" class="hoverNodeundefined" style="fill: rgb(51, 110, 123);"></rect>
    <text x="80" y="0" class="id ">Yes</text>
    <circle class="node fixed" r="58" style="fill: rgb(30, 139, 195); stroke: rgb(21, 97, 136);" transform="scale(1.0)"></circle>
    <text x="0" y="20" class="id">Segment</text>
    <rect class="edit-event node-hover-button" x="-20" y="-70" height="29" width="29" rx="15" ry="15"></rect>
    <rect class="delete-event node-hover-button" x="-54" y="-54" height="29" width="29" rx="15" ry="15"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. But in my case when it's the reverse , that is show on mouseover and hide on mouseout - when i move mouse on to the buttons it will be hidden. That is the issue I'm facing. Any work around for this ? ( in above fiddle when i move mouse on the black button the opacity goes back to 1 )

Comment: @SoorajChandran I just showed you how to create a *selection*. You can use it to make any change you want! Anyway, check my edited snippet.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. The small issue in the above snippet is - I hover on blue circle and the black circle appears, and when i move the mouse to black circle it disappears. Is there a way to stop this is what I meant? I hope I conveyed my point.

Comment: Set their `ponter-events` to `none`. Check my (once again) edited snippet. But have in mind that I already answered your question: how to select the siblings. The problem you're asking here is a *different* problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem is that I have a click event associated to that shape.

Comment: Thus, you have another issue, never mentioned in the question itself. In that case, I suggest you post another question.

Comment: I have added a new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719273/issue-with-mouse-over-and-mouse-out-d3-js

Comment: What if I'm running this code in a Typescript envyronment where `this` is related to the class itself?

Comment: @ErickXavier Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43552367/5768908

Answer (score 1):

While d3 does not have a built in method like `jQuery's` siblings, it's easy with just a little javascript.

```
var children = node.parentNode.childNodes[]  # Gets all child nodes

# Now iterate over all of these nodes
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if (children[i].getAttribute("id") != "id_im_looking_for" {
        d3.select("parent > *:eq(" + i + ")");             # Use d3 select
    }
}
```

Of course you would tailor this algorithm to your code.