# Issue with mouse over and mouse out d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following code:

I have two small circles appearing on mouseover of large circle. The problem I face is - when I move mouse over to the smaller circles it will disappear, from stack overflow found out that adding `pointer-events:none` will stop this. But I need to bind click events on these circles. Is there any work around for this issue ?

```js
d3.selectAll(".node-hover-button").attr("opacity", 0);
d3.select("circle").on("mouseover", function() {
    d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll(".node-hover-button").attr("opacity", 1);
}).on("mouseout", function() {
    d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll(".node-hover-button").attr("opacity", 0);
});

//attach a click event on .node-hover-button.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.7/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <g transform="translate(100,50)">
    <rect x="50" y="-30" width="50" height="60" id="yesDecision" class="hoverNodeundefined" style="fill: rgb(51, 110, 123);"></rect>
    <text x="80" y="0" class="id ">Yes</text>
    <circle class="node fixed" r="58" style="fill: rgb(30, 139, 195); stroke: rgb(21, 97, 136);" transform="scale(1.0)"></circle>
    <text x="0" y="20" class="id">Segment</text>
    <rect class="edit-event node-hover-button" x="-20" y="-70" height="29" width="29" rx="15" ry="15"></rect>
    <rect class="delete-event node-hover-button" x="-54" y="-54" height="29" width="29" rx="15" ry="15"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: just use the same mouseover event on the small circles as you do with the big circle. I.e show (keep open) 2 small circles on mouse over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two possible ways to resolve this issue.

1. Using *toElement* property of d3 event.
2. Group smaller circles and big circle within a separate `<g>` element.

**Method 1:**

```js
d3.selectAll(".node-hover-button").attr("opacity", 0);
d3.select("circle").on("mouseover", function() {
  d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll(".node-hover-button").attr("opacity", 1);
}).on("mouseout", function() {
  var sCircle1 = d3.selectAll(".node-hover-button")[0][0];
  var sCircle2 = d3.selectAll(".node-hover-button")[0][1];
  if (d3.event.toElement != sCircle1 && d3.event.toElement != sCircle2) {
    d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll(".node-hover-button").attr("opacity", 0);
  }
});

//attach a click event on .node-hover-button.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.7/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <g transform="translate(100,50)">
    <rect x="50" y="-30" width="50" height="60" id="yesDecision" class="hoverNodeundefined" style="fill: rgb(51, 110, 123);"></rect>
    <text x="80" y="0" class="id ">Yes</text>
    <circle class="node fixed" r="58" style="fill: rgb(30, 139, 195); stroke: rgb(21, 97, 136);" transform="scale(1.0)"></circle>
    <text x="0" y="20" class="id">Segment</text>
    <rect class="edit-event node-hover-button" x="-20" y="-70" height="29" width="29" rx="15" ry="15"></rect>
    <rect class="delete-event node-hover-button" x="-54" y="-54" height="29" width="29" rx="15" ry="15"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Method 2:**

```js
d3.selectAll(".node-hover-button").attr("opacity", 0);
d3.select(".nodes").on("mouseover", function() {
  d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll(".node-hover-button").attr("opacity", 1);
}).on("mouseout", function() {
  d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll(".node-hover-button").attr("opacity", 0);
});

//attach a click event on .node-hover-button.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.7/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <g transform="translate(100,50)">
    <rect x="50" y="-30" width="50" height="60" id="yesDecision" class="hoverNodeundefined" style="fill: rgb(51, 110, 123);"></rect>
    <g class="nodes">
      <text x="80" y="0" class="id ">Yes</text>
      <circle class="node fixed" r="58" style="fill: rgb(30, 139, 195); stroke: rgb(21, 97, 136);" transform="scale(1.0)"></circle>
      <text x="0" y="20" class="id">Segment</text>
      <rect class="edit-event node-hover-button" x="-20" y="-70" height="29" width="29" rx="15" ry="15"></rect>
      <rect class="delete-event node-hover-button" x="-54" y="-54" height="29" width="29" rx="15" ry="15"></rect>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```