# Binding in constructor vs arrow function in d3 callbacks + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm working with d3 (v3)'s brush feature right now and ran into a situation where binding in the constructor works, but using a class function doesn't. My `.babelrc` is set up for class functions with `"presets": ["flow", "latest", "stage-2", "react"]` and I've gotten arrow functions working in the rest of the code, so it's not a matter of transpilers.

Code in question:

```
    this.brush = d3.svg.brush()
        .x(xScale)
        .on("brushend", this.changeDates)

    const brushGroup = d3.select(this.node).append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .call(brush)
```

If I bind change dates in the constructor as follows, I find that `this` in the function `changeDates` is the React Component `ExampleSVG`, which is the desired behavior.

```
class ExampleSVG extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.changeDates = this.changeDates.bind(this)
    }   

    changeDates() {
        console.log(this) //ExampleSVG {props: {...}, context: {...}}
    }

    ...d3 stuff
}
```

However, if I try binding via the arrow function, `this` becomes the function svg group.

```
class Example extends Component {
    changeDates = () => {
        console.log(this) //<g class="brush" ... />
    }

    ...d3 stuff
}
```

Why is the arrow function not binding (once again, not a transpilation issue, I have plenty of binding arrows in my code)? There's probably something about d3/this that I'm missing here, but I want to figure this out! Is it `call`? In which case, what does `call` do such that it can override arrow binding?

Comment: Your question is misleading: Your syntax is wrong, which renders the question itself invalid. Have a look at the [production rules](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functions-and-classes) for classes. You are not allowed to declare a method using an arrow function. If I put your code in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3pjLhtu/2/) I get a `SyntaxError` complaining about the `:`. Take the second example away and you are left with the first working version, resulting in a pointless question.

Comment: Sorry, where is the colon in my code?

Comment: My bad! It complains about the `=` which is not allowed. You must not do any assignment at that point and, hence, cannot assign the (anonymous) arrow function.

Comment: Just realized that the `=` didn't work in the Fiddle either! I believe this is React syntax—[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvwei/om27zkxr/1/) (with React settings) works without error, so I don't think it's a syntax issue (my code compiles just fine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An arrow function doesn't have its own `this`.

With non-arrow functions passed to D3 selection methods (such as `.attr()`, `.on()`), D3 uses function.apply() to set `this` as the element being modified, which is why it isn't the window (the globally scoped `this` or, if it is not this, the `this` whose scope includes the arrow function).

But, as arrow functions can't have their own scoped `this`, `this` will refer to the whichever `this` has a scope that includes the arrow function.

So, `this` will be different in a typical function as compared to an arrow function. Hence, why you shouldn't use a fat arrow function in a d3 selection method that requires you to select `this` unless you use an alternative way to select that element.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

> In arrow functions, `this` retains the value of the enclosing lexical context's this. In global code, it will be set to the global object ... The same applies to arrow functions created inside other functions: their this remains that of the enclosing lexical context.

---

However, you can certainly keep the arrow function and still reference the element that would be `this`, as the second argument is the current index, and the third argument is an array of elements in the selection. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43552367/7106086) already speaks to this method.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that about arrow functions. So to make sure I have this right, `g.call()` calls the `brush` function, so the fat arrow in brush's `.on('brushend')` will take the `this` of `g`?

Comment: Although your reasoning is correct I think your answer misses the point. Have a look at my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938877/binding-in-constructor-vs-arrow-function-in-d3-callbacks-react#comment88901255_50938877) explaining the issue.

Comment: The reason I ask is because I've also done `d3.select(node).append("rect").on('click', () => {stuff})` in React and the arrow function has taken the React Component's `this`, not the d3 `this` (which I believe is what you're talking about in the latter half of your answer)—the fact that the fat arrow didn't return the same React Component `this` in `brush` was surprising!